# SimpleDateFormat высчитывает даты неправильно

Tags: java, время, simpledateformat

Доброго времени суток. Есть файл, от которого мне нужно узнать, насколько давно он был создан. Вот код:

```
long dm = mFile.lastModified(), t = System.currentTimeMillis();
// dm = 1499499652963
// t = 1499504988843
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date(dm))); //выводит 10:40
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date(t))); //выводит 12:09
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date(t - dm))); //выводит 04:28 - Ошибка
```

Последняя строка кода должна вывести время, сколько часов и минут назад был создан файл. То есть, это должно быть `12:09` - `10:40` = `01:29`. Но никак не `04:28`. Пробовал высчитать разницу немного по-другому:

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date(t).getTime() - new Date(dm).getTime()));
```

Результат не изменился. В чём ошибка? Может я что-то не так высчитываю или это баг JDK? Подскажите, как получить корректный результат в данном случае.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Какой результат возвращает `t-dm`, какой размерности?
Ответ - миллисекунды. А именно, миллисекунды, прошедшие со "старта эпохи", 1 января 1970.

Соответственно, `12:09 - 10:40` дают вам количество миллисекунд, которое при отсчёте от `00:00:00` преобразуется в `04:28`.

Соответственно, если вам нужно найти разницу во времени, используйте следующий подход:

```
Date startDate = someDate;
Date endDate   = anotherDate;

long duration  = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

long diffInSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration);
long diffInMinutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration);
long diffInHours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(duration);
```

Затем, выводите эти значения через нужные форматтеры.

Answer (score 3):

Здесь нет никакой ошибки. То что вы написали, вычисляет разницу, и затем, конвертируется в дату, а она в свою очередь получается *прибавлением этого значения к полночи 1 января 1970 года по UTC* (так называем unix timestamp).

Чтобы получить желаемое значение, можно явно получить из разницы часы и минуты. Например, так:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%s:%s",
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(now - lastModificationTime) % 24,
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(now - lastModificationTime) % 60));
```

> 1:28